# Vector spaces and homogenous linear equations system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For every vector space $R^n$ there is homogenous system of linear equations whose set of all solutions is isomorphic to $R^n$

This should obviously be true, but I am not sure I understand intuition behind it, for example how would I construct a system that is isomorphic, or rather generates $R^3$?

Comment: If we represent the homogeneous system by the matrix equation $Ax=0$, then the only way the solution set is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ (as vector spaces) is if $A=0$.

Comment: Its just identity. So, same identity generates all those spaces, but the difference in just the preset number of variables, or rather format of $x$? If that's the idea behind it.